# prevent npm dependencies from installing in react-native

Tags: javascript, react-native, npm, dependency-injection, package.json

Is there a way to prevent a certain list of dependencies in a package.json from installing when in a certain environment, for example react-native?

I am installing from a web base code to get the redux ducks but with that install comes installing other dependencies that break in react-native. Is there a way to prevent this?

Right now the fix is to manually deleted the undesired installs in my node_modules

Comment: unlikely because the modules will internally depend on the dependent modules. you can manually delete them at the risk of breaking the module functionality.

Comment: In react native I'm only importing what I need so it won't break. So I want them to install on the web, but in rect native I want to prevent them from installing.